# System died when I ran edgetpu_demo

Tags: google-coral

I went to step 7
https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#run-demo
After I hit the command *edgetpu_demo --stream*, the console has the message below and then the system rebooted.

> INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:Listening on ports tcp: 4665, web:
> 4664, annexb: 4666 INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:New web
> connection from 192.168.1.6:62609
> INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:Number of active clients: 1
> INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:[192.168.1.6:62609] Rx thread
> finished INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:[192.168.1.6:62609] Tx
> thread finished INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:New web connection
> from 192.168.1.6:62610 INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:Number of
> active clients: 2
> INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:[192.168.1.6:62609] Stopping...
> INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:[192.168.1.6:62609] Stopped.
> INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:Number of active clients: 1
> INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:New web connection from
> 192.168.1.6:62611 INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:Number of active clients: 2 INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:[192.168.1.6:62610] Rx
> thread finished INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:New web connection
> from 192.168.1.6:62612 INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:Number of
> active clients: 3
> INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:[192.168.1.6:62611] Rx thread
> finished

Need I update some modules such as GStreamer, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Board reboot can occur if board is not getting enough power. Please make sure to boot the board with at least 2.1 - 3 amp of power adaptor.

Comment: Thank you very much. I bought two cables with 3A supported yet I still cannot run the demo. Can you please give me some recommendations about the cable? For instance, the maker name and the product number, etc. BTW, this time the message changed a little bit, here is the newest message:

Comment: BTW, this time the message changed a little bit, with some new information: 
INFO:edgetpuvision.streaming.server:Camera start recording
filesrc location=/usr/share/edgetpudemo/video_stream.mp4 ! qtdemux ! tee name=t
t. ! queue max-size-buffers=1 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=nal ! appsink name=h264sink emit-signals=True max-buffers=1 drop=False sync=False
t. ! queue max-size-buffers=1 ! decodebin ! glfilterbin filter=glbox ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=300,height=300 ! appsink name=appsink emit-signals=True max-buffers=1 drop=True sync=False

Comment: Power adaptor change is just to prevent the board reboot. Is the board still rebooting ?

Comment: Thank you! I bought a power adaptor for Raspberry Pi, and it works.
https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B07DN5V3VN/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_V2HHFJKVRWSGN11D0ZZ8?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1
It turns out that, we have to be careful of the power input to be 5V with 3A.